# contenteditable on an html element in angular template requires a right-click to work properly in chrome

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome

I am using `contenteditable` on my html elements in order to make them editable. The point is that it is working well in Mozilla, but in Chrome I have to right-click on an element and then click on it in order to make it work. I've tested almost all tricks that are mentioned here but there was no progress so far.

I am using Angular 8 and the aforementioned problem happens on html templates of my project.
To be more specific I am adding following code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mb-4">
<div class="text-center">
<h4 class="card-title mb-0 uppercase">EVENT DETAILS/AGENDA</h4>
<p class="mute-text mt-3">Description, time and of the event</p>
</div>
```

to a div which holds "contenteditable" attribute:

```
<div class="panel-body"  contenteditable="true" id="middlepart" 
#middlepart ></div>
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, welcome to SO, please add the link of "here" as you mentioned as well as the code snippet where you are doing `contenteditable` and on which element this is happening.

Comment: As you mentioned I amended my question but there was no response so far. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Teemu can you please help him. I'm not much into HTML. or tag someone who could.